# Can't set tab bar shadow image in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13

Before iOS13, I used the code below to remove the tab bar top border:

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

But it does not work with iOS13, and I am looking for a solution to this. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Swift 4+:**

In your TabBarController class write this:

```
 if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
        appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    }
```

**For title adjustment use this:**

```
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -12)
```

**For Objective C**

```
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    UITabBarAppearance* appearance =  self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy;
    appearance.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
    appearance.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    appearance.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Title adjustment
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -12);
    self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
} else {
    self.tabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But I have other issues now :D I use UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -12) and this code does not work now. I can't adjust titles...

Comment: @VolodymyrDavydenko The issue is solved :D(See answer update) Let me know if this helped you and mark as right answer please.

Comment: @SargisTerteryan can you provide above code in objective - c?

Comment: @SargisTerteryan Thanks for answer, but it's not working. Because "standardAppearance" property not found in tabbar. If you have any other solution than please help me.

Comment: @YogendraPatel For me it's work. Your Xcode version is 11?

Comment: @SargisTerteryan No, My Xcode version is 10. I will update my xcode then check it.

Comment: @YogendraPatel In Xcode 11 that will work fine. Tell me your result after update.

Comment: @SargisTerteryan ok, sure.

Comment: how to set titletextattributes for UItabbaritem using this approach?

Comment: @SargisTerteryan Thanks, code working fine in Xcode 11.

Comment: @dharam You can get standard appear's copy from UItabbaritem and then change it appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = "your attributes"

Comment: @SargisTerteryan Thanks for your answer , its working fine now , thanks a lot

Comment: UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment doesn't work if I use this. Any solutions?

Comment: when I want to change tab bar title color theme-wise then it's not working in iOS13 on appearance. Do you know anything related this ?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13 you can use an appearance based approach with built in methods for configuring transparency:

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    }
```

And to change it back again, you can do the same using configureWithDefaultBackground():

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let appearance = self.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        tabBar.barTintColor = nil
        tabBar.backgroundImage = nil
        tabBar.shadowImage = nil
    }
```

Comment: when I want to change appearance as theme-based, then it's not working. Do you know?